# Algorithms as member or non-member functions?

Tags: c++, encapsulation

I have a simple data structure, a triangular matrix indexed by `k` and `l`, where `l` runs from `1` to `N` and `k` runs from `1` to `l`:

```
template<int N> class triangular_matrix {
    std::vector<int> elem;
public:
    int& operator()(int k, int l) {
        return elem[(N * (N + 1) - l * (l + 1)) / 2 + k - 1];
    }
};
```

I also have several algorithms operating on this data structure. All of them access `triangular_matrix` only via `operator()`.

What are the pros and cons of making these algorithms member functions of `triangular_matrix` instead of making them non-member functions (in a non-global namespace)?

Comment: Well, the principal of the minimal complete interface would say that they should be non-member functions and in this case I would agree. But in my view such questions are over analysed and have no clearly correct answer. Just go with your gut.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ it's common to put everything that doesn't *have to be* a member function in a non-member function. Herb Sutter wrote a [nice article](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm) about it a while back.